# Cannot type 'c' in Terminal - Restore Terminal to default settings

Tags: terminal, keyboard, bash, python

I am new to terminal, learning how to code in Python.

I was trying to turn the autocomplete tab function on, using the code found in the link below.

https://timleland.com/how-to-enable-autocomplete-in-mac-terminal/

I can now not type 'c'. I am able to type 'C' and everything else. I believe I have changed the .bash settings, but I'm an amateur and don't know how to rectify this.

Is there a way to restore Terminal to its default settings?

Many thanks!

Comment: I think you have the same problem as in [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/370052/c-not-working-within-terminal). It doesn't have an official answer, but there's a comment that solved it in that case.

Comment: Thanks so much! This sorted it easily and quickly.

Answer (score 1):

You can remove the broken inputrc file by opening your terminal and moving it to a different name:

```
mv ~/.inputrc ~/.input.broken
```

Then restarting your terminal session should restore it to normal.

In the above  you can copy/paste that in, or just hit tab to complete the first filename. ie. mv ~/.input(tab here) ~/.input.broken